# android - getActionBar() return null

Tags: android

i have a problem with `getActionBar()`, this problem happens when i'm trying to change view of action bar , i'm getting this error:

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{h.ui01/h.ui01.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
            at h.ui01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

My code is here :

```css
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }
}
```

even when i try to hide action bar or change color of the action bar , i saw similar error.

Comment: Try `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. If that doesn't work, please add the code for the `Activity` class you call `getActionBar()` in to your question.

Comment: @PPartisan can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: `final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: Where is this call being made? Depending on where the activity is in its lifecycle, the action bar may not have been created yet.

Comment: Which part has you confused? Just use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`...you will probably need to adjust your `import declaration` as well to `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` from `android.app.ActionBar`. If you're really stuck, just add the code from your `Activity` class where you use the above code snippet :)

Comment: @JordanBondo after setContentView()

Comment: @cricket_007 but ide say : Cannot Resolve method

Comment: Just edit your question to add your full Activity code. That'll be better than us guessing the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 my code added to post

Comment: Could you confirm what the parent `theme` is for your app? Does it extend `@android:style/Theme.Holo` or `Theme.AppCompat` for instance?

Comment: @PPartisan i changed "extends Activity" to "AppCompatActivity" then getSupportActivity() resolved by ide and when try to change color of actionbar , i see no error ! But how can i change view of action bar with LayoutInflate ? Because after using support ActionBar i cannot use above code

Comment: Future reference, when you add code blocks to your questions/answers, use the `{ }` button instead of the other one (which inserts javascript snippets). 4 spaces indicates the start of a code block

Comment: Your best bet is to use a [`ToolBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) instead, then you can design it however you like. Failing that, try `actionBar.setCustomView(view)` instead, wthout the second argument